# How to convert every componets of list which is matrix to data frame?

Tags: r

I have big list and every components of that list is a matrix. I just want to convert every component of that list which is matrix to data frame.  At the end I want to have list, which it's components are dataframe.

Would someone help me to accomblish this task ?

Answer (score 2):

This what you want?

```
x<-list(a=matrix(1:20), b=(matrix(1:20)))
x<-lapply(x, data.frame)
```